# Starvation and Livelock

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization, deadlocks

[image: Scheme]

I think Option C is false. Following is my thought process:

Starvation in general mean Process is waiting indefinitely for the resource or to get scheduled etc. [A/c to Galvin Book]. So, here in this question, Any process needing any resource at any point can call the OWNRESOURCE function and process will surely get the resource it asked for. So, we can surely say that the process doesn't have to wait indefinitely at any point. Hence we don't have Starvation.

But, I have read that Livelock is a special kind of Starvation (Resource Starvation), Clearly the Scheme mentioned in the question suffers from Livelock. But it can't possibly suffer from Starvation.

Questions:

1. Is my thought process correct about Why the scheme can't make process suffer from starvation?
2. Is it possible in the given scheme, to have Livelock but no Starvation?

Note: I have asked similar question(deleted now) but didn't express my thoughts well and didn't have any discussion. Now, I'm very specific about my doubts and I have articulated my thoughts as well.

Comment: I can't tell what your specific question is.  Can you identify a question that you can separate from that specific exercise, and that might be useful to others in the future even if they're not looking at the same exercise?  I would appreciate a clear statement of what the question is.  I'm not sure what "Can any process suffer from Starvation?" means.  "Problem? I have read that..." is not a question.

Comment: @D.W. Sir, I have made edits, Can you please once again go through it? I'm really sorry for the inconvinence.

Comment: We generally discourage "Is my answer correct?" questions, as they're unlikely to be useful to anyone else in the future.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future.

Comment: Sir, Whenever some one have conceptual doubt or faces some other issues or require clarifications on his/her concepts, he/she prefers to come to cs.se and get his/her concepts cleared by the awesome people who are best in their field. Sir, Although negligible chances, but I think there might be possibility that someone faces similar issues in his concepts. Besides, I gave on all what I thoughts not just ask question and expect answer.

Comment: Not everyone on cs.se have worked hard /  is fortunate enough to get his / her doubts cleared by profs in their respective college. Profs that I asked in my college were not aware about livelock.

Comment: On a side aspect, *releasing resources owned by $P$* for grabs by anyone  ***before*** terminating $P$ and its use of these resources looks a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @greybeard, Sir, Once all resources are released only then that process terminates."Terminate P, after releasing all resources owned by P".